# Why isn't Pandas .fillna() filling values in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running Pandas in Python 3 and I noticed that the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import nan

df = DataFrame([[1, nan], [nan, 4], [5, 6]])

print(df)

df2 = df
df2.fillna(0)

print(df2)
```

Returns the following:

```
 0   1
0   1 NaN
1 NaN   4
2   5   6
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1 NaN   4
2   5   6
```

While the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
from numpy import nan

sr1 = Series([1,2,3,nan,5,6,7])

sr1.fillna(0)
```

Returns the following:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    5
5    6
6    7
dtype: float64
```

So it's filling in Series values but not DataFrame values with 0 when I use .fillna(). What am I missing here to get 0s in place of null values in DataFrames?

Comment: Not what's going on here but may help somebody, you can't use df.fillna with df.mean (to replace missing values with column means) if the dtype is not some numeric. Sounds obvious but df.mean() on it's own still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the way you're calling the `fillna()` function.

If you do `inplace=True` (see code below), they will be filled in place and overwrite your original data frame.

```
In [1]: paste
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import nan

df = DataFrame([[1, nan], [nan, 4], [5, 6]])
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: 

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1 NaN   4
2   5   6

In [3]: df.fillna(0)
Out[3]: 
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  4
2  5  6

In [4]: df2 = df

In [5]: df2.fillna(0)
Out[5]: 
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  4
2  5  6

In [6]: df2  # note how this is unchanged.
Out[6]: 
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1 NaN   4
2   5   6

In [7]: df.fillna(0, inplace=True)  # this will replace the values.

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  4
2  5  6

In [9]:
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), the method `fillna(newValue)` returns another `DataFrame` like the previous one, but with the `nan` values replaced by the new value.

```
df = DataFrame([[1, nan], [nan, 2], [3, 2]])
df2 = df.fillna(0)

print(df2)
# Outputs
#   0 1
# 0 1 0
# 1 0 2
# 2 3 2

print(df)
# Outputs (The previous one isn't modified)
#   0   1
# 0 1   nan
# 1 nan 2
# 2 3   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a funny incidence with me, the columns were still showing nan after fillna, finally found that they were being read as "nan" string, so I used replace for "nan" to "0". I hope this helps someone!