# pandas df after fillna() is still NaN

Tags: pandas

A 40000 rows 1 column data saved as excel. There are hundred  null values in it. Such as row 361... 
When I carried out `df.fillna(method='bfill')`, the NaN values is still NaN.
 If sliced a df fragment contained Null values, it processed expectently.
I tried but still could not fill NaN cells.
So what's wrong with it?
The df file is here:

[excel file click here](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DfOdIGsQkL6WBhjYlTE)

```
df=pd.read_execel('npp.xlsx')
df.fillna(method='bfill')
print( df.iloc[360:370,] )
Out[122]: 
          0
t360     NaN
t361     NaN
t362     NaN
t363     NaN
t364  220.50
t365  228.59
t366     NaN
t367     NaN
t368     NaN
t369     NaN
```

When apply `fillna()` on sliced df, the NaN values could be replaced:

```
print( df.iloc[360:370,].fillna(method='bfill') )
       0
t360  220.50
t361  220.50
t362  220.50
t363  220.50
t364  220.50
t365  228.59
t366     NaN
t367     NaN
t368     NaN
t369     NaN
```

Comment: Multiple problems, do you assign output? `df = df.fillna(method='bfill'`) or `df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas .fillna() not filling values in DataFrame in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026705/pandas-fillna-not-filling-values-in-dataframe-in-python-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need assign output:

```
df = pd.read_excel('npp.xlsx')
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')

df = df[df[0].isnull()]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []
```

Or use `inplace=True` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_excel('npp.xlsx')
df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df = df[df[0].isnull()]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []
```

Or shorter:

```
df = df.bfill()
```

---

```
df.bfill(inplace=True)
```

Comment: All right!  Is `df = df.fillna(method='bfill')`  not equal to `df.fillna(method='bfill')`?  A little confused. Why  could small df apply `df.fillna(method='bfill')` carrectly when I tested?

Comment: Yes, it is equal, but this function by default dose not works `inplace`. So is necessary assign or add parameter. It is like `df.sum()` and then check `df` - there is also not sum Series. But works `df = df.sum()` , `df`

Comment: But test a small data using `df.fillna(method='bfill')`, it could run. So what is the difference?

Comment: `fillna` return another `df`, so if no assign or no `inplace=True` then `df` is not changed.

Comment: OK! Thx for ur explaination.